# Php git pull from a branch is not working

Tags: php, git

I can clone the repository by this command:

`exec("git clone pull https://user:password@bitbucket.org/user/repo.git");`

But, can't pull from any branch by this command:

`exec("git pull https://user:password@bitbucket.org/user/repo.git mybranch");`

Any idea?

**UPDATE**:
I found the solution after debugging a lot :)
At first, I cloned my desired branch by this command:

`exec("git clone pull https://user:password@bitbucket.org/user/repo.git --branch branch_name path_to_clone");`

Then created a new file inside the repository ('path_to_clone'). And inside that, added the pull command:

`exec("git pull https://user:password@bitbucket.org/user/repo.git branch_name");`

It works fine!!

Comment: any error messages?

Comment: No, it always return success, but doesn't pull the latest code from the branch.

Comment: I can clone the branch by this way:

`exec("git clone https://user:password@bitbucket.org/user/repo.git --branch mybranch");`

But not sure what's going wrong with pull.

Comment: try to clone with SSH bitbucket link ?

Comment: `exec("git pull git@bitbucket.org:user/repo.git mybranch"); `

Comment: I need https. I can clone it, so, there shouldn't be any issues with authentication.

Comment: @AdittyaVerma Where to set the password in your given format?

Comment: @Shakti I have setup ssh key with my local system so I don't need password in case of SSH.

Comment: Actually I'm using it for auto deployment in my cPanel. It was ok with the same command before some weeks. But now I see it's not working. Looks very strange!

Comment: can you send me some error or screenshot with pull command and its result ? and also once try to restart your system then try this ?

Comment: @AdittyaVerma using the same command as mentioned. No error messages. it returns `Updating bb09c4a..8df9f47`

Comment: This can help you... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10789212/git-fetch-says-success-but-nothing-is-downloaded

Answer (score 0):

According to the [man](https://github.com/tldr-pages/tldr/blob/master/pages/common/git-pull.md)
 You should specify the name of the remote.

```
git pull origin develop
```

Comment: Tried, no result.